# Add two lists which return a list the addition of the adjacent element

Tags: python, list

I want to write a function `add_list`, which adds two lists adjacent elements.
E.g. `l1 = [1, 2, 3]`, `l2= [1,2,3]` should give `[2,4,6]`. I am lost and not sure how to approach it using loops. Can someone help please?

Answer (score 1):

You can iterate both the lists using `zip` and then use `list comprehension` on them

```
[x+y for x,y in zip(l1, l2)]
```

Sample run:

```
>>l1 = [1, 2, 3]
>>l2= [1,2,3] 
>>[x+y for x,y in zip(l1, l2)]
[2, 4, 6]
```

Other possible solution is to iterate through the index  (can be used in list comprehension as well)

```
result = []
for i in range(len(l1)):
    result.append(l1[i] + l2[i])
```

Output:

```
>>result
[2, 4, 6]
```

Comment: List comprehension is indeed a loop

Comment: @Jack, you can take a look at updated answer

Answer (score 0):

The following code will add numbers in two given list provided that both have same number of elements

```
def add_list(a, b):
    result = [] # empty list
    # loop through all the elements of the list
    for i in range(len(a)):
        # insert addition into results
        result.append(a[i] + b[i])
    return result
l1 = [1, 2, 3]
l2 = [1, 2, 3]
print(add_list(l1, l2))
```